# Mention/Reply to users in comments using @ (@name)

Tags: 7, nodes, users, comments

I am looking for a feature that makes it possible to reply to comments, or mention users in a comment using the @ symbol.

So, if I was to write the following in a comment on a node:

> @Michael Jackson Cool stuff dude.

"@Michael Jackson" would turn in to a link that leads to his user page.

Also, if it is possible without to much hassle, it would be great if it only turned in to a link if the user exists, to prevent a 404 error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you might be looking for this module but the 7 version is still in dev.

[Mentions](http://drupal.org/project/mentions)

> The Mentions module offers Twitter like functionality, recording all
>   references to a user's username - using the [@username] or [@#uid]
>   filter format - from various locations, providing a centralized page
>   to track all mentions.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Too bad it is still in dev. I will try it out though, thanks.

Comment: Update: I've tried the dev version of Mentions and it works very good so far. I think the problem with the module is the views integration, but since I am not using that I think it's safe to go with the dev version.

Comment: good to know that it helped. :-)

Comment: This module has issues with ckeditor which currently disallow it to work properly. To learn more see here: https://goo.gl/ubmEGb

Comment: @MohammedShameem I have installed mentions module 7.x-2.x dev. I have created a mention successfully. Now, I want to create hashtags functionality. This version allows to create other input filters as well, but I do not know how to use it to create hashtags. I also installed hashtags module, but it is not working on custom forms. Any suggestions?

Comment: Incase anyone is looking at this there is also https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_mentions